# JSON: Reject server requests from third parties

Tags: java, iphone, json

i intend to use JSON to implement a client server communication. My goal is for a Java-server to receive data via HTTP-Post from an Iphone-app.

I'm concerned about the fact of how I can be sure, that the data the Java-server receives only come from the Iphone-app? It may be possible that somebody else is catching the Java-Server URL and send rigged data?

Do I have a chance to recognize that? SSL encrypts transferred data only, but doesn’t solve the problem, i think.

kind regards

stormsam

Comment: For iPhone you can send udid to webserver so that it is able to detect if udid has some value in it ,that means this request comes from the iPhone otherwise not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send a token that is hardcoded into your application. Everything that comes without this valid toke should be rejected. Or you can use .htaccess and specify a user and password within your app.

Comment: and what if the token being sent is discovered?

Comment: @binnyb, all can be discovered, the question is how far does one want to secure it. You can use 256 SSL encrypted connection. You can use one time tokens that are generated within your app. You can do many things.

Comment: It's not perfect but it's probably the most practical route. (Maybe more helpful if you can give a link to suggestions on how to generate 1-use tokens.)

Comment: See http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2007/04/12/one-time-form-tokens/ and http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_CSRF_anti-spoofing_to_forms

Comment: Given the assumption of the OP that "somebody else is catching the Java-Server URL", a hardcoded token is no improvement at all.

Comment: Thanks, these two approaches are interesting!

Answer (score 0):

You could use public key encryption, with users having their own keys and you keeping track of who are the legitimate users. This is the most reliable scheme I can think of. That, or giving each user a username and password. However, it's probably a lot more trouble than it's worth, and still doesn't protect against users that have registered with you but are still malicious.

Embedding a token in your application and then sending it with requests, as Cyprian suggests, is probably the easiest scheme and would probably work pretty well, but might be relatively easy to reverse engineer.

A somewhat better solution might be to program into your app a function that transforms any given input into an output; then, your server responds to a request by giving the app a piece of data to transform, and checks the result. A client that passes the test gets a session token which allows it to proceed. This does require an extra round-trip for authentication, though. And it's still not immune to being reverse engineered, since all the information needed to do so is stored in the app that's present on the user's machine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can reasonably protect your iOS app from being dissambled, you could use ["signed requests" like the Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) (and probably others):

You'll need a shared secret on both client and server (e.g. a random string/byte array). The iOS app then hashes **all request parameters plus the shared secret** and appends the **hash** as additional request parameter, e.g. `myserver.com/ws?item=123&cat=456` becomes `myserver.com/ws?item=123&cat=456&hash=1ab53c7845f7a`. Upon receiving a request, the server then recomputes the hash from the regular parameters and the shared secret and compares it to the value `sig` parameter. If both are equal, the request is considered valid (assuming integrity of your iOS app).

An advantage of this method is that it **doesn't require additional round trips** to fetch any one-time/CSRF-prevention tokens and does not require encrypting requests and responses (as long as you only care about the integrity of requests, not confidentiality).

Answer (score 0):

You might have to take a look at [this](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/toolbox/article.php/3888106/How-Can-I-Detect-the-iPhone--iPads-User-Agent.htm). It may give you some directions.